# Closed Trajectory for Lotka Volterra System

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the following system of equations:
$\dot{x}=x(1-y)$ and $\dot{y}=\mu y(1-x)$. There are 2 fixed points (0,0) and (1,1) . The fixed point $(1,1)$ is a non-linear center. This can be proved by the following facts

1) the system of equations when linearised about $(1,1)$ gives the fixed point a center behaviour

2)there is a conserved quantity $\mu x-y-\mu \ln(|x|)+\ln(|y|)$ for any trajectory of which the point (1,1) is a global minima.

I found that a few trajectories in first quadrant of $(x,y)$ plot are closed curves.

**Question**: Can it be proved conclusively that all trajectories in first quadrant are closed and cyclic?

This is a part of solution of Strogatz's 6.5.19 d

Comment: Think of the isolines of the said conserved quantity. What are they if not closed curves?

Comment: can't a isoline be a spiral? Saying that they are closed requires some proof.

Comment: Strogatz does not prove it, but states that near a local minima and local maxima, the contours of conserved quantity are closed. $(1,1)$ is a global minima for the conserved quantity. So near the linear center, we have closed orbits, even for this non-linear system. But what about all trajectories in the first quadrant? It is known that the contours are bounded in 1st quadrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's solve it in general. The Lotka-Volterra system, with $a,b,c,d> 0$
$$
x'= x(a-by)\\
y' = y(-c+dx)
$$
has a conserved quantity, or first integral, given by
$$ V(x,y) = by + dx - a\log y - c\log x$$

which we can rewrite as:

$$ V(x,y) = b(y-\frac{a}{b}\log y) + d(x - \frac{c}{d}\log x) = b\,G(y) + d\,H(x) $$

It is useful in this type of exercises to realize that $V(x,y)$ is a convex function:
$$
\nabla V(x,y) = (d-\frac{c}{x},b-\frac{a}{y})\\
\mathcal{H}(V) = 
\pmatrix{
\frac{c}{x^2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{a}{y^2}
}
$$
$\mathcal H $ is positive definite so $V$ is convex. And since the trajectories are contour lines of the function, that gives us an intuition that they will be closed.

The minimum of this convex function is 
$$k_o = dH(\frac{c}{d}) + bG(\frac{a}{b})$$
Both $H$ and $G$ share the same behaviour because they are almost identical save the constant next to the logarithm. They are both convex since their derivatives are precisely those we have calculated to study $V$, and their global minimum $\frac{c}{d}$ and $\frac{a}{b}$ respectively. Besides
$$
\lim_{y\to 0} G(y) = \lim_{y\to \infty} G(y) = \infty
$$
This means that at both sides of $\frac{a}{b}$, $G$ assumes every value above $G(\frac{a}{b})$, and it does it exactly twice, once in $(0,\frac{a}{b})$ and once in $(\frac{a}{b},\infty)$; since it is 1-to-1 in those intervals. Same is true for $H$.

If we fix $\bar k > k_o$ and $\bar x > \frac{c}{d}$, taking into account the previous study, we can find $y_m(\bar x), y_M(\bar x)$ such as
$$
\bar k = dH(\bar x) + bG(y_m(\bar x)) = dH(\bar x) + bG(y_M(\bar x)) 
$$
Let us see what is the range of movement for $x$. Given $k > k_o$, for certain $x,y$ we can write
$$ k = dH(x) + bG(y) =\\
= d\gamma + bG(\frac{a}{b}) \tag{*}$$

What we have done is reduce $G(y)$ to the minimum, and adjust $H(x)$ to a greater value $\gamma \geq H(x)$, to mantain the equality. From the study above we know that there are $x_m, x_M$ such $\gamma \geq H(x)$ for $x \in [x_m,x_M]$. And only the extrema verify $\gamma = H(x_m) = H(x_M)$.

We know that $G(\frac{a}{b})$ is the minimum value $G$ can assume, so $H$ is constrained by this: if $x_o < x_m$ or $x_o>x_M$ then for the $k$ that we chose initially,
$$ k < dH(x_o) + bG(y) \text{ for every y }\geq \frac{a}{b} \text{ (the values permited for y).}$$
What his means is that $x$ must belong in that close interval.

Finally, from the identity $(*)$ follows that
$$
\lim_{x\to x_M}  y_m(x) = \lim_{x\to x_M}y_M(x) = \frac{a}{b}\\
\lim_{x\to x_M}  y_m(x) = \lim_{x\to x_M}y_M(x) = \frac{a}{b}
$$

What we have proven is that for $x \in [x_m,x_M]$ we have continuous functions $y_m(x), y_M(x)$ with $y_m(x) < y_M(x)$ in $(x_m,x_M)$ and $y_m(x_m) = y_M(x_m)$ and $y_m(x_M) = y_M(x_M)$, which verify that, for a given $k>k_o$, 
$$ k = V(x,y_m(x)) = V(x,y_M(x)) $$
and thus we can define two curves $\alpha(x)^+, \, \alpha(x)^-$ such:
$$ \alpha(x)^- = (x,y_m(x),V(x,y_m(x))) = (x,y_m(x),k)$$
$$ \alpha(x)^+ =(x,y_M(x),k)$$
and join them at the extrema to form the close curve of the trajectory $\alpha(x) = \alpha(x)^- - \alpha(x)^+$ (with the usual addition of paths).

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is correct. But why did you have to define $\alpha(x)$. You could have ended with saying that the $\alpha^-(x)$ and $\alpha^+(x)$ endpoints have same coordinates and hence the combination is a closed curve and this closed curve is the entirety of contour of V(x,y)=k.

Comment: you have assumed here continuity of $y_m(x)$ and $y_M(x)$. Do you know some way of establishing it?

Comment: the gradient and hessian of potential function are wrong it seems. the listed values are derivatives of $H(x)$ and $G(y)$ but they need to be derivative of $dH(x)$ and $bG(y)$. Hessian is still positive definite, so the proof is correct. But take a look at this step.

Comment: Yes, I guess I could have stopped earlier, but I wanted to define the closed curve as precisely as I could. And you are right about the gradient and hessian, I slipped there, I have edited the answer. I will think something for the continuity and post it tomorrow.